# Can I give local webcam access to a Azure Win Server VM through Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, azure, webcam, windows-server-2012, rdp

I'm developing a website in VS on a Windows Server Azure VM, and remoting in to do my work through Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac.
The website needs to access a webcam, but I don't have any webcam on the remote windows server!

Is there any way to allow the remote windows server where I'm developing to see my local webcam through Microsoft Remote Desktop, as my local machine is a Macbook Air?

Maybe there's another remote tool for Mac that will allow this? One I have to pay for?

Looking at the settings for Microsoft remote destop for Mac version 10.2.4 how can I set the local resources for USB connections? I don't even see a option for Usb device, just printers, clipboard and Smart cards.

All I see is this below with no options for USB connections

[image]

Answer (score 6):

as of Dec 2018:

no, it is simply not possible with the latest Mac beta [RDP Client](https://aka.ms/rdmac-preview) 
 and a still open demand from [user voice](https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/287834-remote-desktop-for-mac/suggestions/8677648-usb-redirection)

The feature of USB redirection is part of so called RemoteFX and a feature of RDS.
From server side it is possible since Windows Server 2012, newer Versions improved it.
Windows Client (mstsc.exe or remote desktop client) support the USB and Video mapping for since ages, but of course negotiating with the server which features are possible and allowed.

this link gives a nice overview mosty without covering non-Windows:
https://workspot.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214248563-Configuring-USB-Redirection-with-RemoteFX-in-Workspot

to be afraid, the MS Mac client only supports the usual redirections like audio, printer, clipboard and drive mappings.

there are obviously other RDP clients out there, with experimental USB and webcam redirecting:

at least there is [freeRDP](https://www.freerdp.com/) which may also run on a [Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/723795/where-does-macports-install-freerdp)

Comment: Do you know if the configuration settings for Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac supports USB connections like "RDC" for Windows? I'm looking around in the settings and don't see any place to allow USB connections! All I see is is a place to edit local resources but no USB connections. I'll post an image above

Comment: I cannot try it, and this post sounds a bit ambigiuos: https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/287834-remote-desktop-for-mac/suggestions/8677648-usb-redirection. There are users complaining about that missing feature, but there is also a brand new prerelease version from Dez. 11 2019 to test...

Comment: @user1186050 just checked it with a mac an the latest beta client and updated my answer!